# flowplayer embed/object installation

Tags: flowplayer

I am currently using a javascript embed method for flowplayer intallation.

```
$f("player", "{$cyburl}/flowplayer.swf" ,
{literal}
{
    clip:
    {
        scaling: 'fit',
        url: vid,
        provider: 'nginx',
        autoPlay: true
    },

    plugins:
    {
        nginx:
        {
            url: 'flowplayer.pseudostreaming.swf'
        }
    }
}
```

My users often say that they could not play a video. I think this is because javascript embed method. So i decided to embed it with object|embed method. But i can't write correct html code.

```
<param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf" /> 
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="flashvars" 
value='config=???????????????????????????????' />
```

What should i write inside of config section to make it work properly ??

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the docs of Flowplayer [Alternate embedding methods](http://flowplayer.org/demos/installation/alternate/index.html), what you need to do is passed in a config in the form of:
value='config={"clip":"http://blip.tv/file/get/N8inpasadena-Flowers457.flv"}'

There is one big difference between the embed code and the normal javascript that you have to always put a quote around any keys, e.g. the above clip you have to put "clip".
Apart from that, you just follow the same way you did for the standard javascript.

In our work, we usually prefer to use an external configuration file instead of putting all the bits into the flashvars tag.
You can use: 
And then all you need to do is extract your configuration file out from your original code, and add quotes to the keys to this new somefile.js.

However back to your original question, I'm not sure why your user cannot play the video. If it's due to the javascript method, I doubt the embed will work. But you can have a try.

Comment: I am using this string but this is not working for me. What am i doing wrong ? As i understood something wrong with provider:nginx Ex : value='config={"clip":{"url":"http://site.com./file.flv","scaling":"fit","provider":"nginx"},"plugins":{"nginx":{"url":"http://site.com/flowplayer.pseudostreaming.swf"}} }' />